# Force to close error in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and i am now only started.For me when i tried to implement on click listener for a button the application closes.Can anybody help me.

Following is the code:

```
public class Sampleprojectsubbu1Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        final  Button b1=(Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {       
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {           

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: change R.id.button1 instead of android.R.id.button1.

Comment: Accept anyone's answer which was satisfied you.

Answer (score 2):

you are using the id "android.R.id.button1" which is part of android, you should use something like R.id.your_button_id

Answer (score 1):

May be in this line you're having the error -

```
final  Button b1=(Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

in above line `android.R.id.button1` will provide by default button which will coming with android jar.

Instead of there, you've to use the button id. What've you used in your`main.xml` file. Like if you're having one button in your `main.xml` with id of `buttonconfirm` means, you should use like below -

```
final  Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonconfirm);
```

Hope this helps you. And, also please post your `main.xml` with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Please change this line .

```
final  Button b1=(Button)findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
```

to

```
final  Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Comment: Hi I have another problem,the toast is not apperingpublic void onClick(View v) 
  { 
   EditText text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
   
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(text1.getText().equals("subbu"))
   {
    Toast.makeText(Sampleprojectsubbu1Activity.this,"Hello"+ text1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   
  }
 });

Comment: You have to handle this by an event like `addTextChangedListener`. In this implement `onTextChanged` method.